# Rename/Delete audio file from gallery in android programatically

Tags: android

Listed all audio files from gallery ,This is my code to rename and delete list of audio files.By using this code i can able to perform rename and delete operations on list only those are not effecting audio file,How to perform rename and delete operations on audio file in gallery based on my code ,i tried like this by using `File`but didn't work,id there any wrong in my code ,correct me plz
here is my code
Variables

```
ListView myList;
    List values;
    ArrayAdapter adapter;
    MediaPlayerActivity mp = new MediaPlayerActivity();
```

Code to rename and delete by using contextmenu

```
case CONTEXT_MENU_DELETE:

            Toast.makeText(
                    this,
                    "You selected item " + context_menu_number
                            + " from the context menu", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
            Toast.makeText(
                    this,
                    "You removed item " + number_of_item_in_listview
                            + " from the list", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            values.remove(number_of_item_in_listview);
            // myadapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); //if this does not work,
            // reinitialize the adapter:
            adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1,
                    values);
            myList.setAdapter(adapter);
            File f = new File(path + filename);
            if (f != null && f.exists()) {
                // delete it
                f.delete();
            }
            return (true);

case CONTEXT_MENU_RENAME:

        AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        alert.setTitle("öğeyi yeniden adlandırmak");
        alert.setMessage("Seçili öğe için yeni bir isim girin");

        final EditText input = new EditText(this);
        alert.setView(input);

        alert.setPositiveButton("tamam",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                            int whichButton) {
                        String value = input.getText().toString();
                        values.set(number_of_item_in_listview, value
                                + ".3gp");
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        /*
                         * File sdcard =
                         * Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(); File
                         * from = new File(sdcard,"from.txt"); File to = new
                         * File(sdcard,"to.txt"); from.renameTo(to);
                         */
                        File f = new File(path + filename);
                        if (f != null && f.exists()) {
                            File from = new File(f, f.getName());
                            File to = new File(f, value);
                            from.renameTo(to);
                        }

                    }
                });

        alert.setNegativeButton("iptal",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                            int whichButton) {
                    }
                });
        alert.show();
        return (true);
    }
    return (super.onOptionsItemSelected(item));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Rename the files:
Its working fine:Put this code where you want to change the name.

```
File sdcard = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "sample");
            String fromFullPath = "/username556596268.mp3";
            String toFullPath = "/username.mp3";

            File from = new File(sdcard,fromFullPath);
          File to = new File(sdcard,toFullPath);
            from.renameTo(to);
```

here "sample" is my sdcard main directory name,"fromFullPath" is my filename it is in inside the sample directory, "toFullPath" is my changed name.

Answer (score 0):

Delete the files:
Its working fine:Put this code where you want to delete file.

```
File sdcard = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "sample");
            String fromFullPath = "/username556596268.mp3";

            File from = new File(sdcard,fromFullPath);
            from.delete();
from.deleteOnExit();
```